# Get the spreadsheet key that is in the URL. Not ss.getId()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to get the spreadsheet ID that is in the URL. 
I know about using SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId() and SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()

But getId()/getUrl()/getKey() now fails with Google-Drive-SDK. I am no longer able to 
use this ID to open files with the Drive-SDK. It was working about 1 week ago, but the Drive-SDK now fails to open the file.

A workaround is to use the ID that is in the URL. The id after key=

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkGlO9jJLGO8dHJrSE0wTEF2VXRSdGRlNVQaaVRad0E

But I want an automated way to get it, not
a manual process. As the spreadsheet is being created using a template, so I don't have a way to know the ID. Thoughts, is there a way to get it?

Note 1: stackoverflow.com/questions/18583885/ says Google Drive SDK issues should be posted to stackoverflow

Note 2: getUrl() and getKey() contains the same ID as getId() not the key in the URL. So it looks like access to the key has been removed, so am not holding out much hope.

### Edit

The drive code, is Java rather than google-apps-script. version 1.15.0-rc

```
    Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("CellMaster.com.au").build();
    File file = driveService.files().get(this.spreadsheetKey).execute();
```

I think it broke sometime in the last week or so. It fails with the execute(), it produces a 404 error. It gives the error when I use with the short spreadsheetKey that is produced by google apps script. But it still works fine when I use the browser URL key value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show the code that is not working for you, but the following works ok for me

```
function myFunction() {
// create a new spreadsheet workbook
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Test");
var id = ss.getId();
Logger.log(id)
// get the ss file through Drive using spreadsheet id
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var driveid = file.getId();
Logger.log(driveid)
// open the spreadsheet using id of file
var ssfromdrive = SpreadsheetApp.openById(driveid);
Logger.log(ssfromdrive.getName())
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. "var driveid = file.getId();" gives the long spreadsheet key that is in the URL. Thanks. ... Just to document, I added the code that failed, to the question.

Comment: He said "Java" and out posted Javascript

Answer (score 1):

As David pointed out, the id of the same file is different in the Spreadsheet app and in the Drive app.

Getting the spreadsheet file from the Drive app, using the Spreadsheet id, and then getting the id of the Drive file, following the example, will solve your problem.